# I am getting a 404 when I try to pass a jquery var to a method in a controller from view in PHP codeigniter framework

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, codeigniter-3

I wanted to cascade a dropdown based on a parent dropdown selection and i am using a jquery ajax method to perform that. However when i inspect the page it returns 404 page not found.

Should i add anything in the routes?

My method in Controller:

```
public function get_part_by_part_lookup()
{ 
$participant_lookup = $this->input->post('participant_lookup_id'),
header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');    
echo(json_encode($this->participant_category_model- 
>get_part_by_part_lookup($participant_lookup)));
}
```

My view:

```
var participant_lookup_id = $('#participant_lookup').val(); 
$.ajax({
url:'<?php echo base_url(); ? 
>application/controllers/Participants/get_part_by_part_lookup',
type: "POST",                                                                       
data: {participant_lookup_id: participant_lookup_id},
});
```

Comment: use`url:"<?php echo base_url() .'/'.'Participants/get_part_by_part_lookup'",`

Comment: `url` is invalid . correct it:  `url:'<?php echo base_url();?>Participants/get_part_by_part_lookup',`

Answer (score 0):

```
var participant_lookup_id = $('#participant_lookup').val(); 
$.ajax({
url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>Participants/get_part_by_part_lookup',
type: "POST",                                                                       
data: {participant_lookup_id: participant_lookup_id},
});
```

Comment: Thank you guys. Followed ur advise but Still getting 404. Should I add anything to routes?